# react native toLocaleLowerCase working only in debug mode

Tags: javascript, react-native, debugging, filter

I am filtering my data with the code blog below. But filtering correctly working only in debug mode when I turn off debug mode it's not working.

```
filterSearch = (text) => {
    const textData = text.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const newData = this.props.Cities.City_List.filter((item) => {
        const itemData = item.City_Name.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
    });
    this.setState({
        searchTerm: text,
        searchData: newData
    });
}
```

my data like :
`['İZMİR','İSTANBUL','ADANA']`

Comment: same going on here...

Comment: use `toLowerCase()`  instead

Comment: I cant because my data has turkish character and toLowerCase() method not working correctly